# django model wont agree with fixture

Tags: python, django, postgresql, fixtures

I am trying to populate a postgresql database with initial values using fixtures in django. I keep getting these weird `Could not load publication.Article(pk=None): value too long for type character varying(100)`
 errors even though my model looks like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isGraphic = models.BooleanField(max_length=1000, default=True)
    pictures = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    user_img = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    videoname = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    vimeo_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=1000)
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 61, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 91, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 148, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 173, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 698, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 731, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 920, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/sam.royston/PycharmProjects/sahelien_d/sahelien_django/fixtures/test.json' : Could not load publication.Article(pk=None): value too long for type character varying(100)`

why am I getting this error?

test.json:

```
[
    { "model" : "publication.Article" , "fields": 
         { 
           "_id" : "5306dfa9ed2379f03a000001" , 
           "author_name" : "Sahélien Tombouctou", 
           "caption" : "Les  n’ont fait aucune victime, ni de dégâts  matériels",  
           "isGraphic" : false,  
           "pictures" : [], 
           "text" : "La ville de Tombouctou a reçu des tirs d'obus dans la nuit de dimanche. \n<br>\n<br>\nLes deux premiers obus sont tombés dans la localité de Kabara, à 10km de la cité des 333 saints. Le troisième obus est tombé sur la route de Goundam.\n<br>\n<br>\nLes tirs n’ont fait aucune victime, ni de dégâts matériels. Selon le lieutenant-colonel Seydou Koné, en poste à Tombouctou, l'armée malienne est mobilisée pour déterminer l'origine de cette attaque.",                       
           "title" : "Tombouctou attaquée à la roquette", 
           "videoname" : "okok.mp4", 
            "vimeo_id" : "87246621"
         } 
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback (the complete error message).

Comment: Please add your test.json to the question as well. It seems you have a fixture with no primary key.

Comment: aren't primary keys defined implicitly by django?

Comment: Yes, but you still have to add them in the fixtures manually (unless you did a [database dump](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model) in which case they should already be there).

Comment: some problem occurs if I add `pk:1` to the json

Answer (score 0):

Your json fixture is missing a primary key. Django [automatically adds a primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) to your models; called `id`.  As this key is required, you should provide it in fixtures.

The fixture you have posted is does not have this key, you should add it:

```
[
    { "model" : "publication.Article" , "fields": 
         { 
           "id": "1",
           "_id" : "5306dfa9ed2379f03a000001" , 
           "author_name" : "Sahélien Tombouctou", 
           "caption" : "Les  n’ont fait aucune victime, ni de dégâts  matériels",  
           "isGraphic" : false,  
           "pictures" : [], 
           "text" : "La ville de Tombouctou a reçu des tirs d'obus dans la nuit de dimanche. \n<br>\n<br>\nLes deux premiers obus sont tombés dans la localité de Kabara, à 10km de la cité des 333 saints. Le troisième obus est tombé sur la route de Goundam.\n<br>\n<br>\nLes tirs n’ont fait aucune victime, ni de dégâts matériels. Selon le lieutenant-colonel Seydou Koné, en poste à Tombouctou, l'armée malienne est mobilisée pour déterminer l'origine de cette attaque.",                       
           "title" : "Tombouctou attaquée à la roquette", 
           "videoname" : "okok.mp4", 
            "vimeo_id" : "87246621"
         } 
    }
]
```

You are missing key fields that are required in your model from your fixture. You need to add `user_img` and `pictures` cannot be empty.

The fixture needs to pass all the validation rules of your model; and since all fields are required as per your model, they all need to be available in the fixture.

In addition, you have a `max_length` argument for integer, boolean and url fields which are not applicable.

Comment: unfortunately this change yields the same issue: `Could not load publication.Article(pk=1): value too long for type character varying(100)` perhaps there is something else wrong with my setup